# Converting Word table to Latex

Tags: tables

I have the below table which was created in Word. I try the below code, but I do not know how to get the table titles, invoice total, different column width and to spend table across the whole page.

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c||c|c|c|c||c|c|c|c||c|c||c||c||c|c|c|}
\hline 
 &  &   &  &   &   &   &  &  & & & & &  & & & &  &  &  &  \\ 
\hline 
 &  &   &  &   &   &   &  &  & & & & &  & & & &  &  &  &  \\ 
\hline 
 &  &   &  &   &   &   &  &  & & & & &  & & & &  &  &  &  \\ 
\end{tabular}
```

How is it possible to create such Word table in Latex?

[image]

Comment: `\multicolumn`? (http://www.tug.org/tutorials/latex2e/$5cmulticolumn.html)

Comment: I had the same problems when I started LaTeX tables too. I found this very useful: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables and it will answer your questions about table spread, column width and column titles.
However, be warned that it's *not* easy to get LaTeX to apply maths to tables to automatically calculate a total. LaTeX is for typesetting, not spreadsheets

Comment: Related: [How to span the invoice table across whole page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/288672)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[LaTeX Table Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/) is an online tool that allows you to easily generate LaTeX tables. You can create your table with a Microsoft Word-like interface, and the website automatically generates the corresponding LaTeX code that you can copy and paste into your document.

Comment: Even if link may be useful, we try to not rely on them since they can vanish.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try [CalcToLatex](http://sourceforge.net/projects/calc2latex/) for OpenOffice Calc