# How to span the invoice table across whole page

Tags: invoice

I have the below invoice table but it does not fill the whole with of the page.
How is it possible to span the invoice table across whole page width and respecting the margin so more content could fit in the cell?

```
\begin{invoice}{Euro}{0}
  \ProjectTitle{Example Project}%
  \Fee{Development gjgjgj bkgkub kgkugk jhgjgj jkhkjgjkb lhkhkjhjk khh} {1000.00} {1}
\end{invoice}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very rough solution to the problem. Probably this can be seriously simplified using patching tools, hopefully someone will do.

The problem with the `invoice` package is that it defines the width of the activity field as 5cm:

```
    \begin{longtable}{p{5cm}lrrr}%
```

and doesn't seem to give an option to change this. In the following code, I've added another argument to the `invoice` environment to adjust this width. You can find the new `invoice.sty` [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/561b73ec7694a256397bc5da) (select the *invoice.sty* file), just save it with the same name in your working folder. Now, the `invoice` environment will take a third argument for the width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{invoice}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{invoice}{Euro}{0}{6}
  \ProjectTitle{Example Project}%
  \Fee{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  Ut purus elit,vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis} {1000.00} {1}
\end{invoice}
\end{document}
```

You will get:
[image]
You can adjust the width to fit the page.

Comment: invoice.sty -> "Restricted, sorry you don't have permission to load this page."

Comment: Added the edit to `invoice.sty` in an answer below for future LaTeX'ers.

Answer (score 0):

Further to @jak123's answer - you can edit the `invoice.sty` file to pass in a width argument.

A typical location for installed packages via MikTex on Windows is at: `Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\invoice\invoice.sty`

### Before: (invoice.sty)

```
%% Approx at line 228 %%

\newenvironment{\my@invoice}[2]{%

%%... various definitions ...

\begin{longtable}{p{5cm}lrrr}%
```

### After: (invoice.sty)

```
%% Approx at line 228 %%

\newenvironment{\my@invoice}[3]{%

%%... various definitions ...

\begin{longtable}{p{#3cm}lrrr}%
```

The `#3` refers to the third argument's value in the invoice environment. It's value replaces the `#3` parameter directly, as when you pass `10` as the 3rd argument, `#3cm` becomes `10cm`.

### Usage: (myinvoice.tex)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{invoice}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{invoice}{Euro}{0}{10}
  \ProjectTitle{Example Project}%
  \Fee{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  Ut purus elit,vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis} {1000.00} {1}
\end{invoice}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't change files you do not own and don't have the right to change.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the [LPPL-1.3c license](https://spdx.org/licenses/LPPL-1.3c.html) does not permit modification of the `invoice.sty` file. Due to the legal conditions of the CTAN public repository code, the above code change is not permitted.